# In C++, how can I tell WHICH piece of code is allocating what TYPE of objects?

Tags: c++, memory, memory-management, memory-leaks

Note: 
I'm on OSX/Yosemite, so Valgrind is not currently available.
DTrace is, but there is no libc:malloc hook available.

**Statement of problem:**

I have a C++ program that is using too much memory, and I need to know who/what the culprits are.  Note that it does NOT have memory leaks, it's just using too much memory.
In terms of memory use, I need to know:

**WHO**:  It would be nice to know who is allocating the memory (source file, line number).

**WHAT**: It would be nice to know what is being allocated (class name).

I can write my own malloc/calloc/realloc and (sort of) figure it out on my own, but I wanted to see if there are any tools to do this first.

Comment: Compile it for a Linux machine and use Linux tools there.

Comment: Thank you kindly - Could you be more specific?

Answer (score -1, accepted):

You could give dmalloc a try (http://dmalloc.com)

Build from source, link to your program, then play with the utility functions in http://dmalloc.com/docs/latest/online/dmalloc_13.html

(disclaimer: I don't use OSX so the above might not work)

Comment: Thanks - but this seems to tell you more about stats on the byte level (e.g., 12345 bytes were allocated) and doesn't seem to tell you anything about the C++ level (e.g., Base::Derived allocated 1235 bytes of class Data).  So, not really a solution to what I was looking for (but thank you).

Comment: dmalloc has location tracking, so at least you should be able to see which line of code allocated which chunk of memory.

Answer (score 0):

Turns out it was a lot easier to just use Linux virtual machine with Valgrind massif :)
Hooray for virtual machines!